# Which version of Photoshop should I use?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

I want to learn photoshop, I'm a web developer/designer.

[image: My System Config is]

I want to know which version of Photoshop can I install in my system, so that it can run smoothly without any lagging.

Comment: [Photoshop system requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html).

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version, **Photoshop CC 2015**. No point learning on an outdated piece of software, especially considering all of the web-focused tools Adobe are adding to their software at the moment.

If you're studying you should be able to get a Creative Cloud subscription with a student discount, which will give you access to Photoshop, Illustrator and Adobe's new program Experience Design CC, which they're hoping will be their Sketch killer.

Otherwise, if you just want Photoshop, Adobe offer a plan for photographers which includes Photoshop and Lightroom for around $10 a month.